# Text files are no longer affected by hiding or unhiding the exension (.txt)

Tags: extension

I have become used to Windows and the process for hiding or unhiding the extensions of files so that the extensions will not appear in File Explorer display, renames, or the Property window.  This makes it easy to rename files and keep the hidden extensions intact.

Somehow this has become broken for text files (.txt) only.  Whether I designate extensions to be hidden or unhidden, the ".txt" extension is still visible on File Explorer and Property windows.  If extensions are hidden, it does not allow the extension to be overwritten.  This is as it should be.  But the extension should not be appearing at all.

Other file types are not affected in this manner.  Their extensions all vanish when I designate extensions to be hidden.  Only text files (.txt) are acting peculiar.

This is not a critical problem, just an annoyance.  I have to remember to get the base file name from the Property window and dele the extension before selecting. Otherwise, I could easily get a redundant ".txt" in the file name (e.g. "name.txt.txt") upon renaming.

Does anyone have any thought how this might have happened and how I could fix?

Comment: Letting us know the exact version of Windows may be useful. Please [edit] the question and add this information.

Comment: Could you include in your post the contents of the registry keys `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile`. Screenshots are enough.

Comment: why do you need to hide extensions just to keep the extension intact while renaming? Explorer already just selects the name part when renaming

Comment: This is the default behavior for files that are not associated with a program. As soon as you make .txt open with Notepad, it should be back to what it used to be.